# Как задать хороший вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение

**Как же заставить себя читать справки, искать, изучать? Как увеличить вероятность ответа на свой вопрос? Как задать вопрос правильно?**

Пояснение: Если вы пришли на сайт, на котором дают ответы, почему же нет вразумительного ответа в результатах поиска на вопрос - "Как задать хороший вопрос?" ??? Очевидно что спросят... ))

Comment: Эм, если вам нужно заставлять себя читать справки, то, видимо, всё уже безнадёжно

Comment: ну ок... пусть мой пример послужит другим. )

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это уже не вопрос, а утверждение.

Comment: А никак не надо. Если вы не задали хороший вопрос, то вас, видимо, не так уж и интересует ответ. Если вам _реально_ нужен ответ, то вы будете стараться прояснить всё, что можно, и будете изо всех сил помогать отвечающим; вопрос при этом автоматически станет хорошим.

Comment: Если все так, то почему по прежнему наблюдаются такие результаты: [https://www.businessballs.com/amusement-stress-relief/tree-swing-cartoons-new-versions/]

Comment: @A_Vaclav: потому что тем, кто отвечает за результат, тоже не так уж и надо?

Comment: @A_Vaclav потому что "такие результаты" не имеют ни малейшего отношения к тому, как задать вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Постараться задать его коротко и ясно. Описать в кратце чем занимаешься, что хочешь получить. Буквально в две строки, потом пишешь сам вопрос где описываешь препятствие для достижения конкретно поставленной задачи. Этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Вот так вот задашь кратко и ясно, а тебе @Дух сообщество пишет... "что то деталей не хватает..." ))

Comment: Раньше писал не Дух, но на enSO попросили убрать лимит на число таких комментариев...

Comment: A_Vaclav, краткость краткости рознь) Это общие слова) Для кого то кратко два слова, а для кого то два абзаца )))

Answer (score 2):

[Читаем тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Ну и не верьте тому, что лень - двигатель прогресса.

Comment: `"Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа."` -- да, это супер -) Очевидно, что если данное условие в самом деле выполнено, то спрашивать уже не стоит, поскольку (насколько я вижу)  бла-бла (т.е. обсуждения, развернутый обмен мнениями, в общем, непринужденная беседа) на интересные темы тут уже давно не приветствуется.

Comment: @avp а что, непринужденная беседа когда-то была допустима? Во времена хэшкода разве что...

Comment: @andreymal, да, во времена хэшкода. Новый контингент, задисциплинированный  enSO, пресек  эту свободу

Comment: @andreymal Это миф, насколько я знаю. На Хэшкоде не только не пощрялись беседы, но и было ограничение в 4 комментария от одного участника под одним вопросом, и чата при этом не было.